# MySQL Wont Start?

Tags: mysql, opensuse

I am using OpenSuse.

When I try starting mysql on my system it by running after installing MySQL.

```
rcmysql start
```

I then get this message.

> Job for mysql.service failed because the control process exited with
>   error code. See "systemctl status mysql.service" and "journalctl -xe"
>   for details.

after running these two commands.

```
systemctl status mysql.service
```

> ● mysql.service - MySQL server    Loaded: loaded
>   (/usr/lib/systemd/system/mysql.service; disabled; vendor preset:
>   disabled)    Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2018-07-31
>   22:57:28 CDT; 4min 2s ago   Process: 21381
>   ExecStartPost=/usr/lib/mysql/mysql-systemd-helper wait (code=exited,
>   status=1/FAILURE)   Process: 21380
>   ExecStart=/usr/lib/mysql/mysql-systemd-helper start (code=exited,
>   status=1/FAILURE)   Process: 21369
>   ExecStartPre=/usr/lib/mysql/mysql-systemd-helper upgrade (code=exited,
>   status=0/SUCCESS)   Process: 21359
>   ExecStartPre=/usr/lib/mysql/mysql-systemd-helper install (code=exited,
>   status=0/SUCCESS)  Main PID: 21380 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Then I run

```
journalctl -xe
```

> Jul 31 21:48:00 linux-kfrm org.kde.kwalletd5[2699]: kwalletd5 started
>   Jul 31 21:48:00 linux-kfrm org.kde.kwalletd5[2699]: openAsync for 
>   ":1.4" Jul 31 21:48:00 linux-kfrm org.kde.kwalletd5[2699]: Setting
>   useNewHash to true Jul 31 21:48:00 linux-kfrm org.kde.kwalletd5[2699]:
>   Wallet new enough, using new hash Jul 31 21:48:00 linux-kfrm
>   org.kde.kwalletd5[2699]: fsize:  957594615  encrypted.size():  47528 
>   blksz:  8 Jul 31 21:48:00 linux-kfrm org.kde.kwalletd5[2699]:
>   Application ' "kded5" ' using kwallet without parent window! Jul 31
>   21:48:00 linux-kfrm org.kde.kwalletd5[2699]: Migration agent
>   starting... Jul 31 21:48:00 linux-kfrm org.kde.kwalletd5[2699]: old
>   wallets were already migrated Jul 31 21:48:00 linux-kfrm
>   org.kde.kwalletd5[2699]: Migration agent stop. Jul 31 21:48:07
>   linux-kfrm org.kde.kwalletd5[2699]: Setting useNewHash to true Jul 31
>   21:48:07 linux-kfrm org.kde.kwalletd5[2699]: Wallet new enough, using
>   new hash Jul 31 22:01:41 linux-kfrm su[5573]: (to root) sdrafahl on
>   pts/2 Jul 31 22:01:41 linux-kfrm su[5573]: pam_unix(su:session):
>   session opened for user root by (uid=1000) Jul 31 22:01:41 linux-kfrm
>   su[5573]: pam_systemd(su:session): Cannot create session: Already
>   running in a session Jul 31 22:01:41 linux-kfrm su[5573]:
>   pam_unix(su:session): session closed for user root Jul 31 22:01:41
>   linux-kfrm su[5578]: (to root) sdrafahl on pts/2 Jul 31 22:01:41
>   linux-kfrm su[5578]: pam_unix(su:session): session opened for user
>   root by (uid=1000) Jul 31 22:01:41 linux-kfrm su[5578]:
>   pam_systemd(su:session): Cannot create session: Already running in a
>   session Jul 31 22:15:28 linux-kfrm su[5578]: pam_unix(su:session):
>   session closed for user root Jul 31 22:16:26 linux-kfrm su[16763]: (to
>   root) sdrafahl on pts/0 Jul 31 22:16:26 linux-kfrm su[16763]:
>   pam_unix(su:session): session opened for user root by
>   sdrafahl(uid=1000) Jul 31 22:16:26 linux-kfrm su[16763]:
>   pam_systemd(su:session): Cannot create session: Already running in a
>   session Jul 31 22:18:05 linux-kfrm su[16949]: (to root) sdrafahl on
>   pts/2 Jul 31 22:18:05 linux-kfrm su[16949]: pam_unix(su:session):
>   session opened for user root by (uid=1000) Jul 31 22:18:05 linux-kfrm
>   su[16949]: pam_systemd(su:session): Cannot create session: Already
>   running in a session Jul 31 22:18:05 linux-kfrm su[16949]:
>   pam_unix(su:session): session closed for user root Jul 31 22:18:05
>   linux-kfrm su[16954]: (to root) sdrafahl on pts/2 Jul 31 22:18:05
>   linux-kfrm su[16954]: pam_unix(su:session): session opened for user
>   root by (uid=1000) Jul 31 22:18:05 linux-kfrm su[16954]:
>   pam_systemd(su:session): Cannot create session: Already running in a
>   session Jul 31 22:35:27 linux-kfrm su[2970]: (to root) sdrafahl on
>   pts/4 Jul 31 22:35:27 linux-kfrm su[2970]: pam_unix(su:session):
>   session opened for user root by (uid=1000) Jul 31 22:35:27 linux-kfrm
>   su[2970]: pam_systemd(su:session): Cannot create session: Already
>   running in a session Jul 31 22:35:27 linux-kfrm su[2970]:
>   pam_unix(su:session): session closed for user root Jul 31 22:35:27
>   linux-kfrm su[2977]: (to root) sdrafahl on pts/4 Jul 31 22:35:27
>   linux-kfrm su[2977]: pam_unix(su:session): session opened for user
>   root by (uid=1000) Jul 31 22:35:27 linux-kfrm su[2977]:
>   pam_systemd(su:session): Cannot create session: Already running in a
>   session

I have tried uninstalling mysql and reinstalling but with no effect.

When I try doing `mysql -u root -p`
and enter the password I get this message.

> ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket
>   '/var/run/mysql/mysql.sock' (2 "No such file or directory")

How do I fix this problem and install mysql so I can login?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The portion of your error log which says

```
Cannot create session: Already running in a session Jul 31 22:35:27
```

often means that something is already connected on the port that mysql needs to use.  This often happens when a previous start attempt fails but is still connected to the port that mysql needs to use.  Another less likely reason is that a different program is already using that port.

If you installed mysql using it's defaults then it's trying to use port 3306 which is the normal port for mysql.  So, it's not likely that another program is using the port.  It's most likely still connected from a prior failed mysql start.

Type

```
netstat -an | grep -i 3306
```

This will tell you if you have a process using the mysql port.  You will probably see something like:

```
# netstat -an | grep 3306
tcp        0      0 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:3306         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
```

which means you already have something running on the mysql port.  So, type:

```
lsof -i :3306
```

and you should see something like:

```
COMMAND   PID  USER   FD   TYPE  DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
mysqld  NNNNN mysql   14u  IPv4 1400263      0t0  TCP hostname:mysql (LISTEN)
```

which will tells you which program is using the port.  Get the PID of the process and kill the process with

```
kill -9 NNNNN
```

Then try restarting mysql again